# Is there any Twitterizer 2.4.2.dll available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, twitter

I am working on a app in which user will search in twitter throw my app. but i could not found any Twitterizer 2.4.2.dll i found only package manager installer every where i have vs 2008 in vs 2008 there is not a pk manager
some of sites tell alternative of pk manager but those are long processess.
i want short solution is there any Twitterizer 2.4.2.dll available ??? so that i connect with twitter

OR  there any other way to connect with twitter ??? istead of  Twitterizer 2.4.2 ??

at the momnet i am using LinqtoTwitter.dll my code is

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey = "xxxx",
                ConsumerSecret = "xxxx"

            }
        };
        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

        var queryResults =
            from search in twitterCtx.Search
            where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                  search.Query == "Linq To Twitter"
            select search;

        Search srch = queryResults.Single();


        srch.Statuses.ForEach(entry =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                "ID: {0, -15}, Source: {1}\nContent: {2}\n",
                entry.StatusID, entry.Source, entry.Text));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

but it is giving me `Bad Authentication data
Exception

is there opensource dll availabe so that i connect with twitter not with pk manager ??? `

Comment: Hi Nomi, Please see my question and answer here. There is a link to the GitHub project that has examples in asp .net and MVC. Please upvote if it is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

With the ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer, you must call Authorize(), like this:

```
var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
    {
        ConsumerKey = "xxxx",
        ConsumerSecret = "xxxx"
    }
};

auth.Authorize();

var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
```